# What does r in smp.symbols(r'\theta_1 \theta_2', cls=smp.Function) mean?

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to sympy, and I am following a guide to using it for physics.

There's a line which says:
 `smp.symbols(r'\theta_1 \theta_2', cls=smp.Function)`

What does the *r* before the `'\theta_1 \theta_2'` means? I have not been able to find anything...

So far, I have noticed that removing it

[Screenshot without the r, using jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaKOe.png)

kind of messes with the variable name, given that it has a \ for "LaTeX".

Thanks for any insights you may provide!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r"xxx"` indicates a "raw string", in which backslash escapes are not processed.  The string `"\theta"` by itself contains 5 characters: a tab, and the letters "heta". But the string `r"\theta"` contains 6 characters: a backslash, a 't', and then 'heta'.

You can also write `"\\theta_1 \\theta_2"`, but raw strings save you from having to double the backslashes.